# SpringBoot RestTemplate Connection Pooling: Managing Stale Connections

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am using RestTemplate with ConnectionPooling using PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager as in below code :

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new 
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(DEFAULT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS);
    
connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(DEFAULT_MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE);
    connectionManager.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(new 
HttpHost(excConfig.getImsServerEndpoint())), IMS_ROUTE_MAX_CONNECTIONS);

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpReqFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpclient);
    httpReqFactory.setReadTimeout(DEFAULT_HTTP_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
    httpReqFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(DEFAULT_HTTP_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
    httpReqFactory.setConnectTimeout(DEFAULT_HTTP_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);

    restTemplate = new RestTemplate(httpReqFactory);
```

Does RestTemplate take care of terminating stale connections by itself? Or do I need to put in some specific handling for the same?

Answer (score 2):

By default it does not, but you can configure it easily in your `CloseableHttpClient` configuration.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(true))
    .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
    .build();`
```

Source [here](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-connection-management).

Answer (score 2):

`setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled` has become obsolete.

HttpClients.custom()
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom().<strike>setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(true)</strike>)
    .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
    .build();

In HttpClient 4.5.3 the below code works -

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager 
          = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(20);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connManager).build();
```

Comment: Dandy one question :
Even if we use setValidateAfterInactivity(), do we still need to have idle monitor thread to close the idle connections?

`
 public Runnable idleConnectionMonitor(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager pool) {
  return new Runnable() {
   @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "10000")
   public void run() {
    if (pool != null) {
     System.out.println("pool stats>"+pool.getTotalStats());
     
     //pool.closeExpiredConnections();
     //pool.closeIdleConnections(idleConnectionCloseThreshold, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
   }
  };
 } 
`